# Displaying small images with their original size in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, size

I have two small images.

When I run the code below, my images are displayed in a larger size. I mean images are displayed with fit sub plots. I just want to display my small images original size not fitted size.

```
figure,subplot(121);imshow(IM1);
subplot(122);imshow(IM2);
```

I tryed `axis image` and `truesize` but failed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sets the size of the axis the figure is shown in to the number of pixels in the original image...

**Note: this will stop the axis from automatically resizing with the figure window**

```
Hax = subplot(2,2,4);
imshow('image.bmp');

[x,y] = size(imread('image.bmp'));
set(Hax,'units','pixel');
pos = get(Hax,'position');
pos(3:4) = [y,x];

set(Hax,'position',pos)
```

The image will start in the bottom left of where the subplot axis was previously
to make it appear in the center add the following line just before `pos(3:4) = [y,x];`

```
pos(1:2) = ceil([pos(1)+pos(3)/2-y/2,pos(2)+pos(4)/2-x/2])
```